# How to use ko.observable Arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem using ko.obserbaleArrays...

this is my observable Array

```
self.favoriten = ko.observableArray([
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit1", isFavourite: false
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit2", isFavourite: true
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit3", isFavourite: false
                }
                ]);
```

Now I want to set the "isFavourtite"- Property with a function looking like this:

```
  self.makeFavourite = function (projectName, data, event) {
      //Some Code

        };
```

I don't really now how to set this property with knockout.js

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
  self.makeFavourite = function (projectName, data, event) {
      var favorite = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.favoriten(), function(item){
          return item.projectName == projectName;
      })

      if (favorite){
          favorite.isFavourite = data;
      }
  };
```

But if you want to the values updated in UI you have to make projectName and isFavourite observable. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/UdsDf/

Comment: this made it a favourite, but somehow the observableArray is not updatet!
meaning: I display a picture depending on if it's a favourite or not, but the picture status is not updated

Comment: From the documentation: "Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects" - this means you will have to make the array items observable themselves.

Comment: isFavorite field should be an observable for automatic UI update.

Answer (score 1):

Use ko.utils api inside of makeFavorite function

```
var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.favoriten(), function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.projectName, projectName);
        });
if (item)
    item.isFavorite = true;
```